# WPF MVVM Async event invoke

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, async-await

I am lost in this one, i want my Viewmodel to use a event delegate so i can subscribe to it, open some dialog and wait for the dialog result. Later the ViewModel should do whatever it wants with the dialog result.

Here is how i implemented it (resumed code):

```
public class MyViewModel()
{
   public delegate TributaryDocument SearchDocumentEventHandler();
   public event SearchDocumentEventHandler SearchDocument;

   //Command for the search button
   public CommandRelay SearchDocumentCommand { get; set; }

   //Document that i found in the dialog.
   public TributaryDocument Document { get; set; }

   public MyViewModel()
   {
      SearchDocumentCommand = new CommandRelay(DoSearchDocument);
   }

   //The command execution
   public void DoSearchDocument()
   {
       //Event used here !
       Document = SearchDocument?.Invoke();
   }
}

public class MyUIControl : UserControl
{
    public MainWindow MainWindow { get; }

    public MyUIControl()
    {
       MainWindow = Application.Current.Windows[0] as MainWindow;
       DataContextChanged += MyUIControl_DataContextChanged;
    }

    private void MyUIControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var modelView = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
        modelView.SearchDocument += MyUIControl_SearchDocument;
    }

    private TributaryDocument MyUIControl_SearchDocument()
    {
       //Dont know what to do here... i am lost on this part.
       return await MainWindow.ShowDialog(new MyDocumentSearcherDialog());
    }
}

//The signature for MainWindow.ShowDialog
public async Task<object> ShowDialog(object dialog)
{
   return await DialogHost.Show(dialog, "MainDialog");
}
```

`MyDocumentSearcherDialog` is just a dialog where i search and return a `TributaryDocument` object.

The problem to my understanding comes from this part (since i cant compile it):

```
private TributaryDocument MyUIControl_SearchDocument()
{
   return await MainWindow.ShowDialog(new MyDocumentSearcherDialog());
}
```

I cant use await without changing the method signature to async. If i change it to async then i must return a `Task<TributaryDocument>` and change the event delegate:

```
    public delegate Task<TributaryDocument> SearchDocumentEventHandler();

    //On MyUIControl
    private Task<TributaryDocument> MyUIControl_SearchDocument()
    {
       return await MainWindow.ShowDialog(new MyDocumentSearcherDialog());
    }

   //On MyViewModel
   public async void DoSearchDocument()
   {
       //Event used here !
       Document = await Task.Run(async () => await SearchDocument?.Invoke());
   }
```

If i do this i get the following exception:

> Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many
>   UI components require this.

Comment: You have told us what you want to and you've provided your code, which is good, but you haven't explained exactly how the current code doesn't meet your needs. We should not have to guess or work out things that you already know.

Comment: You should solve this with a service interface which has an async method SearchDocumentAsync. One implementation will invoke the dialog

Comment: There, updated with i've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like all you need to do is to remove the `Task.Run` (there is no need to *Offload* to another thread in this situation). The `Task.Run` will definitely give you a *STA Thread Exception* if you are doing *UI* work from within.

However, in short the *Async and Await Pattern* will create a continuation with the current *SynchronisationContext*, so there is no need to worry about it.

```
public async void DoSearchDocument()
{ 
   await SearchDocument?.Invoke();
}
```

<sub>***Note** : Since this is an event, it's about the only place it's OK to use `async void`.*</sub>